# Replace the text for all files in a Directory

Tags: powershell

I have written the below conditional script to go through the files in the directory and replace the one text in all files only if file contains the word as 'Health'

```
cd -Path "\\shlhfilprd08\Direct Credits\Temp2"
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\shlhfilprd08\Direct Credits\Temp2"))
{
$filecontent = Get-Content -path $file -First 1
if($filecontent -like '*Health*'){$filecontent = $filecontent -replace 'TEACHERF','UniHlth '}
Set-Content $file.PSpath -Value $filecontent 
}
```

I come across with two issues such as

1. If the ($filecontent -like '*Health*'), it is replacing the word in first raw and deleting other rows along with replace.I do not want that to happen
2. I'm getting set-content to path is denied error message for file content does not contain the Health text

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with this

```
cd -Path "\\shlhfilprd08\Direct Credits\Temp2"
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.config -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
 {
  (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
   Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "TEACHERF", "UniHlth " } |
   Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: did not work. the files does not have any extension. it just says the type as 'file'

Comment: And also, if condition is missing in the above code ($filecontent -like '*Health*'), It does not require to update any files which does not have the 'Health' text

Comment: Its working for me just remove the extension i tried with one file so i put extension .config. You just need to go with $configFiles = Get-ChildItem . * -rec

Comment: Sorry mate, it worked. the Issue was .* rather than . *

Answer (score 0):

I would try this; it worked for me in a little file
(make a small copy of a few data into a new folder and test it there)

```
$path = "\\shlhfilprd08\Direct Credits\Temp2"
$replace ="TEACHERF" #word to be replaced
$by = "UniHlth " #by this word (change $replace by $by)


gci $path -file | %{
    foreach($line in $(Get-content $_.Fullname)){
        if($line -like $replace){
            $newline = $line.Replace($($replace),$($by))
            Set-Content $_.FullName $newline
        }
    }
}
```